# What are 'user' and 'system' times measuring in R system.time(exp) output?

Tags: r, time

I am using `system.time(expression)` to measure execution time for an R function.

The output I get for the call

```
system.time(myfunction())
```

is:

```
    user  system elapsed   
  117.36    5.65  127.86
```

What does 'user' and 'system' measure?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)#User_Time_vs_System_Time

Comment: This question could use a better title--such as "What are 'user' and 'system' times measuring?". This would make the question clearer to people browsing the list.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is discussed in `?proc.time` (`system.time()` returns an object of class `"proc.time"`):

```
Details:

     ‘proc.time’ returns five elements for backwards compatibility, but
     its ‘print’ method prints a named vector of length 3.  The first
     two entries are the total user and system CPU times of the current
     R process and any child processes on which it has waited, and the
     third entry is the ‘real’ elapsed time since the process was
     started.
```

....and

```
Value:

....

     The definition of ‘user’ and ‘system’ times is from your OS.
     Typically it is something like

     _The ‘user time’ is the CPU time charged for the execution of user
     instructions of the calling process. The ‘system time’ is the CPU
     time charged for execution by the system on behalf of the calling
     process._
```

Answer (score 58):

The clearest explanation I've ever read on the difference between `user` and `system` elapsed time was provided by [William Dunlap on [R-help]](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Meaning-of-proc-time-tp2303263p2306691.html):

> "User CPU time" gives the CPU time spent by the current  process
>   (i.e., the current R session) and "system CPU time"  gives the CPU
>   time spent by the kernel (the operating  system) on behalf of the
>   current process.  The operating  system is used for things like
>   opening files, doing  input or output, starting other processes, and
>   looking at  the system clock:  operations that involve resources that
>   many  processes must share.

Although `?proc.time` returns something similar, this description was a lot easier to understand for me.

Answer (score 33):

Here is some simple explanations:

***Elapsed Time*** is the time charged to the CPU(s) for the expression.

**User Time** is the wall clock time. The time that you as a user experienced.

Usually both times are relatively close. But they may vary in some other situations. For example:

- If **elapsed time > user time**, this means that the CPU is waiting around for some other operations (may be external) to be done.
- If **elapsed time < user time**, this means that your machine has multiple cores and is able to use them

Comment: I think you may have "elapsed time" and "user time" reversed (in your definitions; the examples you give make sense to me). For example, when running code that uses parallelization, `user` can be *much* greater than `elapsed`, since in a single tick of wall clock time, an army of CPU's can expend a lot of "user" time.

Comment: An experiment shows me that the real time is the _elpased_ time, so as @DanielKessler seems to be right here

Answer (score 18):

Since these are generic anyway, from Wikipedia:

> The term 'user CPU time' can be a bit
>   misleading at first. To be clear, the
>   total time (real CPU time) is the
>   combination of the amount of time the
>   CPU spends performing some action for
>   a program and the amount of time the
>   CPU spends performing system calls for
>   the kernel on the program's behalf.
>   When a program loops through an array,
>   it is accumulating user CPU time.
>   Conversely, when a program executes a
>   system call such as exec or fork, it
>   is accumulating system CPU time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)#User_Time_vs_System_Time

Answer (score 2):

Since those time variables are defined by your OS, you can retrieve information on how they are calculated by executing `man time` in your shell (on Unix):

> ...These  statistics  consist of (i) the elapsed real time between invocation and termination, (ii) the user CPU time (the sum of the `tms_utime` and `tms_cutime` values in a struct tms as returned by times(2)), and (iii) the system CPU time (the sum of the `tms_stime` and `tms_cstime` values in a struct tms as returned by times(2)).

The definition of the mentioned time variables can be [found here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/times.h.html):

> `tms_utime`  User CPU time.
>
> `tms_stime`  System CPU time.
>
> `tms_cutime` User CPU time of terminated child processes.
>
> `tms_cstime` System CPU time of terminated child processes.

A a clarification of the differences between user and system time is described in daroczig's answer and [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097691/2166823):

> The `tms_utime` element is the amount of time spent executing your code, or the code in the C library. The `tms_stime` element is the amount of time spent in the kernel executing code on your behalf.