# What's the difference between tms_utime and tms_stime with the times() function?

Tags: c++, cpu

What's the difference between `tms_utime` and `tms_stime` exactly? I'm referring to the `struct tms` used by the POSIX [`times()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/times.html)
 function.  Is the data caching time included in the `utime`? Can the data caching time be measured separately?

PS: I am using Linux-Ubuntu. For example, I am solving a large sparse linear equation system using my C++ program.

Comment: You'll likely need to provide a bit more context.  Probably, utime is the time spent in user-land executing the program, while stime is the time spent by the kernel executing work on behalf of your program.  However, that's a guess because you've not given enough context for a good answer.

Comment: Hmm, I am the kind of amateur programmers who know little about the computer science. :) What kind of context do I need to provide? I am running a C++ program to do some engineering simulations.

Comment: The context you need to provide is where you plan to get the `utime` and `stime` values from, if they are structure members, or what the function calls do if you're referring to two different system calls, or ...  If you want to refer to functions, it is simple to add parentheses after their names (`stime()` and `utime()`) which would go a long way towards disambiguating what you are referring to.  This is also an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You'd do best if you explained what you want to do and ask if either function will help you with solving that.

Comment: `utime` and `stime` I mentioned are `tms_utime` and `tms_stime` from `<sys/times.h>`, please see this link: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/times.html.

Comment: OK; with that, my first comment applies as (more or less) accurate.  The `tms_utime` element is the amount of time spent executing your code, or the code in the C library.  The `tms_stime` element is the amount of time spent in the kernel executing code on your behalf.  (The `tms_cutime` and `tms_cstime` are the sums of the `tms_utime` and `tms_stime` respectively for all the child processes that have exited — see the rationale commentary.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jon. I know these definitions of utime and stime. But I just don't understand them. So I asked this question. It might sound weird to you, but I am curious to know if data caching time can be measured or not. So by these measurement, I could say, you need to modify your solution algorithm, or say, you need to buy a CPU with a bigger L3 cache.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you are discussing the `tms_utime` and `tms_stime` members of `struct tms` (which contains 4 elements of type `clock_t`) used by [`times()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/times.html), the difference is as outlined in my first and last comments:

> The `tms_utime` element is the amount of time spent executing your code, or the code in the C library.  The `tms_stime` element is the amount of time spent in the kernel executing code on your behalf.  (The `tms_cutime` and `tms_cstime` are the sums of the `tms_utime` and `tms_stime` respectively for all the child processes that have exited — see the rationale commentary.)

There is no breakdown of the time into 'time spent waiting for the cache' vs 'time spent not waiting for the cache'.  I think the cache time would be included in the `tms_stime` value because when the data isn't in the cache, you will need the system to fetch it for you.

Comment: I tested with my my program on a 256 core job simulation, the stime is no more than 0.5s, the utime is around 50s. My program is solving a sparse linear equation system. So it sounds like the data-caching time is included in the utime.

Comment: Are you definitely sure "There is no breakdown of the time into 'time spent waiting for the cache' vs 'time spent not waiting for the cache'."? As I read some articles on writing a cache friendly code, I really want to know how cache-friendly my code is.

Comment: I'm 99+% sure there isn't information about cache vs non-cache code with `times()`. All else apart, its resolution isn't large enough (`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is usually 60 or 100). There probably are calls to determine the cache vs non-cache time, but they are going to be platform-specific and hence different for different platforms. You do say you're using Ubuntu (Linux), so you should look up profiling options.  I've not needed to do that level of timing.  I tend to just time the performance of the program under different regimes and ... well, I don't often need to do that sort of profiling.