# getURL working slow

Tags: r, xml, linux, web-scraping, rcurl

I am extracting information from various databases, and to accomplish that I am keeping track of how to convert between the different IDs for each database.

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")
transformDrugId<-function(x){
URLtoan<-getURL(x)
PARSED<-htmlParse(URLtoan)
dsource<-xpathSApply( PARSED,"//*[@id='advancedform']/div[7]/fieldset/p/b[1]/text()",xmlValue)
id<-xpathSApply( PARSED,"//*[@id='advancedform']/div[7]/fieldset/p/a[1]/span/text()",xmlValue)
return(c(dsource,id))}
```

And just as an example the time that it takes on my PC using linux and RSTUDIO is

```
system.time(DBidstest<-sapply(urls[c(10001:10003)],transformDrugId))
 user  system elapsed 
0.132   0.000   3.675 

system.time(DBids7<-sapply(urls[c(601:700)],transformDrugId))
user  system elapsed 
3.980   0.124 549.233
```

Where urls contain the list of url adresses  of the TDR database where I check for IDs
The computation time becomes prohibitively long when I have to do this for the 300000 drug IDs.
 As an example I provide the first five urls

```
head(urls)
[1] "http://tdrtargets.org/drugs/view?mol_id=608858"
[2] "http://tdrtargets.org/drugs/view?mol_id=608730"
[3] "http://tdrtargets.org/drugs/view?mol_id=549548"
[4] "http://tdrtargets.org/drugs/view?mol_id=581648"
[5] "http://tdrtargets.org/drugs/view?mol_id=5857"  
[6] "http://tdrtargets.org/drugs/view?mol_id=550626"
```

Any help that might help in reducing the time to get and analyse the htmls will be apreciated. I am open to any suggestion that might involve not using R.

I have later realized that  using getURLAsynchronous for 10 or less URL is sometimes faster, but using it twice becomes slower

```
system.time(test<-getURLAsynchronous(urls[c(1:10)]))
user  system elapsed 
0.128   0.016   1.414 
system.time(test<-getURLAsynchronous(urls[c(1:10)]))
user  system elapsed 
0.152   0.088 300.103
```

Comment: Though not the speediest, I wonder if "computation time" isn't your problem here as much as the potential for network latency. When I see a network operation taking >500 seconds of elapsed time and <4 seconds of user time, I lean towards either network problems or checking the size of data being tranferred. (For a reference, [explanation of the time fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5689000/3358272).)

Comment: Each web page downloaded weights 50kb, I have also tried using getURL asynchronous but the time does not seem to improve. How can I check if it is a latency issue and solve it?

Comment: Are the times the same if you use `download.file`?

Comment: When I use download.file times lower by 1/3       system.time(download.file(urls[c(1:3)],c("test1","test2","test3")) )

   user  system elapsed 
  0.024   0.000   1.013

Comment: So it sounds like `download.file` is faster (in this case) than `getURL`, perhaps you can use the former to download it and then xml-parse the downloaded file. Does the time-to-download vary by time-of-day? In the past I've noticed some performance differences between `RCurl` and `httr` (which uses `curl`, a similar but distinctly different interface to `libcurl`), and though I can't quantify it now, I suggest you look into trying `httr`.

Comment: Thank you, httr should do the job faster in R as it includes handle sharing by default of requests to the same web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading directly using the shell resulted ten times faster
    echo $URLTEST| xargs -n 1 -P 7 wget -q
where URLTEST is a list of htmls to download.-n sets the waiting time between queries and -P the number of parallel queries, both where fine tuned so that for 100 htmls I got
    real    0m13.498s
    user    0m0.196s
    sys     0m0.652s

There must be some problem in how R's interface t libcurl, that makes it really slow in comparison both for getURL() and downloadFile()