# Interpreting proc.time() output

Tags: r

```r
tm <- proc.time()
... # some code
tm <- proc.time() - tm

message(tm)
```

When I run the above code, I get an output like this:

343.5052.0511567.85400

What do these numbers represent? How do I find the time elapsed from this?

Comment: From [`?proc.time`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/proc.time): *"The first two entries are the total user and system CPU times of the current R process and any child processes on which it has waited, and the third entry is the ‘real’ elapsed time since the process was started."*. These are all for the currently running process. Perhaps you want `system.time({ some code })` instead? To use `proc.time`, I'd use `proc.time()[3]` and `proc.time()[3] - tm` for real-world elapsed time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688949/what-are-user-and-system-times-measuring-in-r-system-timeexp-output/23447134#23447134

Comment: @r2evans any idea why there are 4 numbers separated by points?

Comment: Oh, yes, `message` defaults to concatenating strings. See `message(1:3)` to see. And since it doesn't honor `sep=` (as `cat` and others do), you'll need to manually break them up. If you must `message` them, then `paste(proc.time()[1:3], collapse = " ")`.